# Running .launch file by maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to run test suite(.launch file) with maven sure-fire-plugin.
I have file TestSuite.launch in src/test/resources.
This is my pom.xml file:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/TestSuite.launch</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

and when i try to run 'mvn test' from command line I've got ClassNotFoundException.

Is it possible to run .launch file from maven(for .java class that works good)? If yes how can I do that?

regards

Comment: I believe that .launch files contain Eclipse launch configurations. The Maven surefire plugin can't parse them. You'll have to include the TestSuite (if you have a TestSuite class) or Testcases classes directly.

Comment: One approach could be, if possible at all, to run a headless Eclipse and get it to run the test suite. But I don't see the point, it's much simpler to run your unit tests directly from the maven surefire plugin

Comment: Yes, I have .java class - TestSuite.java and I didn't have any problems with run it in maven plugin. I just wanted to know if it is possible to run this launch configuration. regards